# MySQL error when adding special characters, specialy at sign, even with mysql_real_escape_string() method

Tags: php, mysql, insert, special-characters

I am tying to make a user system with a mysql database. I have tried to insert a row into a table with the following php code:

```
$UserCreateQueryText = "INSERT INTO  users (
Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, eMail, ID, ClearanceLevel)
VALUES (
" . $User . ", " . $Password . ", " . $FirstName . ", " . $LastName . ", " . $eMailToUse . ", NULL, 1)";

$UserCreateQuery = mysql_query($UserCreateQueryText) or die(" User creation query error: " . mysql_error());
```

The Variables I used are defined as follows:

```
$User = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["Username"]);
$Password = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["Password"]);
$FirstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["FirstName"]);
$LastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["LastName"]);
$eMail = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["eMail"]);
```

I used $_GET so I could see the variables were actually being passed correctly.

So, if I inserted a eMail (example@domain.com) the result of $UserCreateQueryText would be:

```
INSERT INTO  users (
Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, eMail, ID, ClearanceLevel)
VALUES (
username, password, Name, LastName, , NULL, 1)
```

so getting the eMail field clear and an error is thrown back:

```
User creation query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
' NULL, 1)' at line 4
```

-Ric Del ([foxtailgames.com.mx](http://www.foxtailgames.com.mx))

Comment: That's a problem with your query. Try echoing it instead, and run it in phpmyadmin and see what comes up to try to figure it out. The query isn't properly formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote string values:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ('String', 'string', ...)
```

Currently you're not:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES(Foo, Bar@baz.com, ...)
```

That gives the syntax error.

Comment: `echo` your final query with the inserted values and post it here.

Comment: I did:

INSERT INTO  users (
Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, eMail, ID, ClearanceLevel)
VALUES (
username, password, Name, LastName, , NULL, 1) (Email stays empty)

Comment: Well there's your problem, you have that empty comma.

Comment: @ricky Yup, and the `, ,` is causing a syntax error, **because you did not put quotes around your values**. Even if the syntax would be correct, you'd get another error because the values aren't in quotes. Also, you're calling your email variable `$eMailToUse` here and `$eMail` there, which is why it stays empty. Activate error reporting to catch such typos!